# Error when building a project with CURL lib?

Tags: c++, libcurl

Error when building a project with CURL,
Collected using g++, version

```
g++.exe (Rev5, Built by MSYS2 project) 10.2.0
Copyright (C) 2020 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

CURL was established using the MSYS2.

Code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <curl\curl.h>

#define CURL_STATICLIB

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    CURL* curl = curl_easy_init();

    if (curl)
    {
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "https://www.google.com");

        CURLcode res = curl_easy_perform(curl);

        if (res != CURLE_OK)
            exit(-1);

        curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Error:

```
undefined reference to `__imp_curl_easy_init'
undefined reference to `__imp_curl_easy_setopt' 
undefined reference to `__imp_curl_easy_perform'
undefined reference to `__imp_curl_easy_cleanup'
```

Command:

```
g++ main.cpp -lcurl -static
```

What am I doing wrong?
Update, add new errors:

```
 undefined reference to `__imp_getnameinfo'
 undefined reference to `__imp_ntohs'
 undefined reference to `gai_strerrorW'
 undefined reference to `__imp_freeaddrinfo'
 undefined reference to `__imp_WSAStartup'
```

Comment: Looks like you are not linking to the curl lib. You will have to show how you are compiling your code for help.

Comment: No, I'm linking it,
command:
g++ main.cpp -lcurl -static

Comment: You have to define `CURL_STATICLIB` before including cURL header

Comment: After I put CURL_STATICLIB in front of the header, there were even more errors

Comment: Please add the errors to the question

Comment: added, these are not all errors, because the site does not allow to insert everything, there are a lot of them

Answer (score 0):

First off, you should always use forward slashes in header file paths.
Second, you shouldn't link to libcurl statically - it's way easier to just link dynamically; dynamic linking makes programs start up faster and is easier to use. In fact, I tried to link a libcurl program statically, but linking that is a nightmare (on MSYS2).

tl;dr: Linking statically to libcurl is not worth the effort.

Comment: But this doesn't answer his question.

Comment: I tried this for a few more hours than I should've, and I think it might be impossible. There's probably some weird arcane way to do it, but I couldn't find it.